# USB Serial Communication Console Application

Tags: c++, c, console, serial-port, usb

I'm working on a project that involves data transfer from a host PC to the ngx Xplorer 433x microcontroller evaluation board which has a NXP - LPC 4330 uC on it.

I have read and seen that the USB Communication Class Device has interface descriptors for communication and bulk data transfer.

So far I can send commands/files via hyperterminal (TeraTerm) but the throughput is about 32kbit/s, so apparently the transfer is being done via the communication class interface descriptor. The goal should be to achieve a speed of about 10mbit/s or more and ideally it should be controled over a command window (and later a nice GUI).

So far I have been looking for example code on bulk data transfer on USB without any luck, all I found were some odd Microsoft examples that require Win8,VS2013,etc.

Basically what I'm looking is something like:

```
data[<some big number>] = "<many letters and stuff>";
port_send(COM8,data);
// end
```

I would greatly appreciate any link, tutorial, pdf, code snipped that could get me further.